# Send email is not sending email when used nodemailer with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smtp, protractor, nodemailer

No message is displayed for the error but also for the message for success is also not displayed. Also no email is recieved.

This is the code i had in the config file of protractor. Here there is no error response for the email but also there is no successful message also and no email is received.

this is in the config file

```
    onComplete: function () {

     creating reusable transport method (opens pool of SMTP connections)
            var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
                host: "smtp.company.com",
                port: "110",
                auth: {
                    user: "anuvrat.singh@companyemail.com",
                    pass: "XXXX@2015"
                }

            });

      setup the email data
            var mailOptions = {
                from: "anuvrat.singh@Company.com", // sender address
                to: "anuvrat.singh@Company.com", 
                subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
                text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
                html: "<b>Hello world ✔</b>" // html body
            }

   send mail with defined transport object
                smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {

if there is an error it will display other wise it will send the message
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                }
 shut down the connection pool, no more messages
                smtpTransport.close();

            });

    }
```

Comment: Please include in your question a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: didn't got you?

Everything is mentioned...the code which i have written